# JavaScript SetDate Error

Tags: javascript

From my understand that adding days to a current Date object in Javascript works like this :

```
    var today = new Date("4/28/14");
    var twoDays = new Date();
    twoDays.setDate(today.getDate() + 2);
```

And it is working for me half the time. Though this set of code:

```
    var today = new Date("4/28/14");
    var twoDays = new Date();
    twoDays.setDate(today.getDate() + 2);
    var oneWeek = new Date();
    oneWeek.setDate(today.getDate() + 7);
    var twoWeeks = new Date();
    twoWeeks.setDate(today.getDate() + 14);
```

is returning this for me:

```
    Mon Apr 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)
    Wed Jul 30 2014 16:37:38 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)
    Mon Aug 04 2014 16:37:38 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)
    Mon Aug 11 2014 16:37:38 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)
```

For some reason it is skipping into July and August when it should be going into June only. Can someone help me figure out why this is acting this way? Clearly 14 days after April 28th isn't in August.

Thanks!

Comment: Re: `new Date("4/28/14")`, don't do that. Parsing of date strings is entirely implementation dependent, except for the format specified in ECMA–262, which is not supported by all browsers in use or consistently by those that do support it.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing

```
var twoDays = new Date();
```

which sets it to today.  Not your variable `today`, but to today, 7/14/2014.

Then you do `twoDays.setDate(today.getDate() + 2);` which sets the date to `30`, because the day portion of `today` the variable is `28`.

Everything else is this same mistake but with other variables, so hopefully you can figure it out from there.

Comment: Ah... I knew was doing something dumb. Thank you!